# Line graph with multiple factors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have a graph that looks okay but I am trying to convert it to a line graph. However, I cannot seem to get it to work and create multiple factors like I have previously. How can I convert my first plot to a line graph with 4 lines?

This is my original graph, with the code as follows (I know there are some weird mistakes):

```
ggplot(data = temp, aes(x = test, y = value, shape = factor(CASE.CONTROL))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean", size = 5, aes(col = factor(gender)))+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Case/Control", values = c(2,3))+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Gender", values = c("red","blue"))
```

[image: img1]

This is what my line graph looks like so far, but obviously there is plenty wrong with it. I need to have 4 lines, as in, male/case, female/case, male/control, female/control.

```
ggplot(data = temp, aes(x = test, y = value, group = factor(gender),group = factor(CASE.CONTROL))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = "mean", size = 2, aes(group = factor(CASE.CONTROL)))+
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = "mean", size = 2, aes(group = factor(gender)))+
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = "mean", size = 2, aes(col= factor(gender)))
```

[image: img2]

This is what the line graph looks like so far but obviously there are major issues. I must be simply missing something simple here, how can I make a line graph that shows equivalent info from the first one?

Comment: You say obviously there are issues, but without knowing exactly what you want, it's unclear what those issues are. If you want lines through your data points, just use `geom_line` (call it *once*) and map color to whatever variable you're splitting lines by. It's hard to help beyond that without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Share output of `dput(temp)`. [edit] your question and add the results of that in the body of your post.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a group for the lines first to make it easier:

```
set.seed(100)
temp = data.frame(
test=rep(1:5,each=3,times=4),
value=rnorm(60,rep(1:4,each=15),0.5),
CASE.CONTROL = rep(c("case","control"),each=30),
gender = rep(c("M","F"),each=15,times=4)
)

temp$line_group = with(temp,paste(gender,CASE.CONTROL))
```

I think it's quite confusing to have 4 colors again for your different groups, but try the 2 suggestions below.

only black lines:

```
ggplot(data = temp, aes(x = test, y = value, shape = factor(CASE.CONTROL))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean", size = 5, aes(col = factor(gender)))+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Case/Control", values = c(2,3))+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Gender", values = c("red","blue")) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = "mean", size = 1, 
  aes(group = line_group),col="black")
```

[image]

Or a consistent color (I changed one of the case/control to circle so we can see it):

```
ggplot(data = temp, aes(x = test, y = value, shape =line_group,col=line_group)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean", size = 5)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(2,1,2,1))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","red","blue","blue")) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = "mean", size = 1, 
  aes(col=line_group))
```

[image]